# Need to only allow editing on double click for p:cellEditor within p:dataTable. Single click should just select row

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

This sounds like it should just be a basic thing that I need to do, but I can't figure it out. I am using Primfaces 6.0 and Mojarra 2.2.13. I have a p:dataTable with multiple p:column's. Each of the columns has a p:cellEditor, some have p:calendar's and some have h:inputText's. I need to have all cell's be non-editable with a single click, I just want the row to be selected on single click. I only want the cell editor to kick on on double clicks. I've messed with the p:ajax rowDblselect event but it doesn't change the behavior. Anybody have an example on how to do this? Here's the basic code. I didn't put the bean code, it's just a basic bean where locations is just an ArrayList of Location objects.

```
    <p:dataTable scrollable="true" editable="true" id="locationTable" editMode="cell" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{location.id}" selection="#{bean.selectedLocation}" value="#{myBean.locations} var="location">
        <p:column width="35" headerText="col 1">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="location.id"/>
                </facet>
                <:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="location.id"/>
                </facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
```

...more columns